# How are if statements written in Excel

Tags: excel, math

I need to divide tickets into certain columns depending on the amount of tickets sold.

Tickets Sold: 100

```
            1-10    11-50   51-100  100+ (tickets sold)

            10      40      50      0
```

So obviously it would limit 10 to the first column, 40 to the second, 50 to the third and the remainder would be in the 4th column. It needs to calculate per column how many of the sold tickets needs to go to a specific column.

Example 2:

Tickets Sold: 33

```
            1-10    11-50   51-100  100+ (tickets sold)

            10      23      0      0
```

I know how to do this with javascript but I'm not quite affiliated with excel scripting.

How can I write this expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that K1 contains the number of tickets and that the first row contains the upper boundaries you can use:

```
10                 50                             100
=K1-MAX(0; K1-A1)  =$K1-SUM($A2:A2)-MAX(0;$K1-B1) =$K1-SUM($A2:B2)-MAX(0;$K1-C1)
```

The second column formula can be pulled across.

[image]

Comment: Hey @schnurstrax, thankyou for your response, I can clearly see that this is working by your screenshot, although does google docs not support something in this statement? It's just saying "REF" when i try recreate it, thankyou!

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Am-rMmDk9ra6dDlOdlhYYWRiU1FVNVFmTGNWNjN3N3c

Comment: I checked it in google docs and it works for me.

Comment: Sorry, This was my fault, how can I do the last colum though? the 100+ colum, at the moment I have `=IF(B2>100, B2 - 100)` which seems to work fine, but how can I set it to "0" if it is not greater than 100

Answer (score 0):

Example 1:

```
=IF(A2>10, 10, IF(A2>50, 50, "Less than 10 tickets sold"))
```

Example 2:

```
=IF(AND(A2>1, A2<11), 10, IF(AND(A2>11, A2<51), 23, IF(A2>50, 0, "NA")))
```

Comment: Hey, this helps a bit, thankyou, although how can I calculate the "Tickets Sold" automatically, without having to manually specify per column. So if they enter in 40 tickets sold, it would automatically put 10 in the "Less than 10" column and 30 in the "less than 50" column etc

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Am-rMmDk9ra6dDlOdlhYYWRiU1FVNVFmTGNWNjN3N3c You should be able to view this spreadsheet from the link mate

Comment: I would like to recommend you removal of file share due to data privacy protection ...

Comment: I've shared it to aid myself, these are all backups :)

Comment: Try this: http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g1712472b61c5e8b81702529dd8ce259d45c62c; I hope that is what you asked for :) Going to sleep now...

Comment: Thankyou for your work, although it's still not what I'm after, see @schnurstrax reply, his image is exactly what I'm after :(